# Working of Handlers and Asynctask in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

I wanted to know if any one can explain the control flow of the following tutorial :
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

I am not aware of how does Runnable and post() method of Handler work?

Thanks

Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1 :**

```
Handler threadHandler=new Handler();
        threadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do your task here ..it will execute after 100 ms in separate thread 
            }
        }, 100L);
```

**Example 2:**

```
     final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        new Thread(){
                            /* (non-Javadoc)
                             * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
                             */
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
    // do your task here.. it will execute in seperate thread
// you can post your result from here using mHandler.post Method.
                        }       
                        }.start();
```

there are many tutorials is available on internet. you can find it very easily.

see this :

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

Runnable represent a runnable bloack of code as Object, and post method in handler, requries a runnable object as input, to which handler executes.